# How to trigger a particular button click event automatically on each change in front end input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an order page where I need to get all product prices and apply some calculations to find out the final price.
I have done all these calculations and displayed the results there using button click event by jQuery.

But whenever I update the input fields, I need to click on the button to update previously calculated result and show new one.

How can I'm done this without button click? If any change in the whole content happened, I need to trigger the button click automatically.

If it is possible to do via Ajax, Can you please help me?

Please find my current jQuery code given below.

```
//Update data corresponding to change in value of days field
$(document).on('change', '#order-edit-extracost', function(e) {
    var days = $('#order-edit-extracost').val();
    var cost = (parseFloat(days) * 0.5).toFixed(2);
    $('#order-edit-extracost-sum').val(cost);
})

// Order page Price calculations
$(document).on('click', '#calculate-cost', function(e) {
    var prev_cost = $('.total-prev').html();
    var prev_cost_float = parseFloat(prev_cost.match(/-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)/)[0]);
    var wastetype_sum = 0;
    //find sum of all wastetype rows
    $( '.order-wastetypeRow' ).each(function( index ) {
      var wastetype_price = $(this).find('#order-edit-wasteprice').val();
      prev_cost_float = parseFloat(prev_cost_float) + parseFloat(wastetype_price);      
    });
    //calculate VAT and add it to the sum
    var extra_cost = $('#order-edit-extracost-sum').val();
    var final_cost = (parseFloat(prev_cost_float) + parseFloat(extra_cost)).toFixed(2);
    $('.est-cost').html("CHF "+final_cost);
    var vat_in_float = parseFloat(final_cost);
    var vat_amount = (vat_in_float * 0.077).toFixed(2);
    $('.final-vat').html("CHF "+vat_amount);
    var total = (parseFloat(final_cost) + parseFloat(vat_amount)).toFixed(2);
    //show calculated costs
    $('.final-amount').html("CHF "+total);
    $('#finalcost-layout').show();
    $('.submit-cost').show();
});
```

Comment: *possible to do via Ajax* - where is your calculation? Looks like it's in javascript.  Ajax is for making calls to a server/service.

Comment: Calculations part are all done. It is working fine with the above code. The problem is, right now I need to click the button to update the result. Is that possible automatically?

Can we do the button click event automatically when ever any change in the DIV happened? Is that possible with Ajax.

Comment: So there are multiple inputs that affect the calculation, and on change of each of these you want to trigger a calculation function yes?

Comment: Exactly!

I have multiple input fields, The output cost is depends on each of them.

Comment: Put you function in a ...function... and call it on `input` event: `$(document).on("input", "input", calculate_function)` `$(document).on('click', '#calculate-cost', calculate_function);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so first of all I just want to point out that there is a much more convenient way of attaching event listeners to elements in jQuery. Like so:

```
$("#order-edit-extracost").change(function(){
});

$("#calculate-cost").click(function(){
});
```

Now to answer your question, as @freedomn-m said, Ajax is generally for making calls to a server/service. What you want can be achieved without it. So first off, you should make a function that does the calculation, like so:

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var prev_cost = $('.total-prev').val();
    var prev_cost_float = parseFloat(prev_cost.match(/-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)/)[0]);
    var wastetype_sum = 0;

    //find sum of all wastetype rows
    $( '.order-wastetypeRow' ).each(function( index ) {
      var wastetype_price = $(this).find('#order-edit-wasteprice').val();
      prev_cost_float += parseFloat(wastetype_price);      
    });

    //calculate VAT and add it to the sum
    var extra_cost = $('#order-edit-extracost-sum').val();
    var final_cost = (parseFloat(prev_cost_float) + parseFloat(extra_cost)).toFixed(2);
    $('.est-cost').html("CHF "+final_cost);
    var vat_in_float = parseFloat(final_cost);
    var vat_amount = (vat_in_float * 0.077).toFixed(2);
    $('.final-vat').html("CHF "+vat_amount);
    var total = (parseFloat(final_cost) + parseFloat(vat_amount)).toFixed(2);

    //show calculated costs
    $('.final-amount').html("CHF "+total);
    $('#finalcost-layout').show();
    $('.submit-cost').show();
};
```

Next, in order to attach the input fields to the function, you can add the `oninput` attribute to the HTML syntax, like so:

```
<input class="total-prev" type="text" oninput="calculateTotal()"/>
```

Or, you could use a selector that is common to the elements, like the `class`, and attach the `input` event listener by looping through them. Like so:

```
$('.input').map(function() {
    $(this).on('input', calculateTotal);
});
```

What the `input` event will do is that it will be triggered every time something is input to the field.

Answer (score 1):

you can add below trigger function inside of on change event method.

```
$( "#calculate-cost" ).trigger( "click" );
```

like below

```
$(document).on('change', '#order-edit-extracost', function(e) {
var days = $('#order-edit-extracost').val();
var cost = (parseFloat(days) * 0.5).toFixed(2);
$('#order-edit-extracost-sum').val(cost);
$( "#calculate-cost" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, all of you, for helping me out. I have done it as like @KhalidFazal suggested.